# elastic beanstalk django app CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS is missing scheme or netloc

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i have a django app that previously was able to deploy to elastic beanstalk, but after making changes to add django-cors-headers and deploying i receive the below error in cfn-init-cmd.log:

```
2023-12-17 04:45:04,829 P24040 [INFO]   
2023-12-17 04:45:04,829 P24040 [INFO]   ERRORS:
2023-12-17 04:45:04,829 P24040 [INFO]   ?: (corsheaders.E013) Origin 'clothing-calculator-env.eba-qnfpfgsz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com' in CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS is missing scheme or netloc
2023-12-17 04:45:04,829 P24040 [INFO]       HINT: Add a scheme (e.g. https://) or netloc (e.g. example.com).
2023-12-17 04:45:04,829 P24040 [INFO]
```

These are some snippets from my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "main.apps.MainConfig",
    "storages",
    'corsheaders'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",

]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http://clothing-calculator-env.eba-qnfpfgsz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com',
    '*',

]
```

The wierd thing is that the first time i got this error, i didnt have the http://. After i added it, the error didnt change at all. I even went to elastic beanstalk to deploy a older version of the app before any of these changes and still get the same error, which is strange because in that version CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS didnt even exist in settings.py